# Javascript Grouping and Sorting

Tags: javascript, sorting, arraylist

I have random cities list as below . How can I group and sort it with below criteria

1. SortAndGroup function should take input of the countryCode and sort accordingly with capitol city on each group at first position followed by cities in that country. Thank you for your help.

   randonCities =

   ```
     [
            {
                "name": "Delhi",
                "countryCode": "IN",
                "isCapitol": true
            },
            {
                "name": "New York",
                "countryCode": "USA",
                "isCapitol": false
            },
            {
                "name": "Birmingham",
                "countryCode": "UK",
                "isCapitol": false
            },
            {
                "name": "London",
                "countryCode": "UK",
                "isCapitol": true
            },
            {
                "name": "Hyderabad",
                "countryCode": "IN",
                "isCapitol": false
            },
            {
                "name": "Chicago",
                "countryCode": "USA",
                "isCapitol": false
            },
            {
                "name": "Bristol",
                "countryCode": "UK",
                "isCapitol": false
            },
            {
                "name": "Washington",
                "countryCode": "USA",
                "isCapitol": true
            }
        ]
   ```

   End Result should be

   sortByCountry(USA, UK, IND) =

   ```
    [
        {
            "name": "Washington",
            "countryCode": "USA",
            "isCapitol": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Chicago",
            "countryCode": "USA",
            "isCapitol": false
        },
        {
            "name": "New York",
            "countryCode": "USA",
            "isCapitol": false
        },
        {
            "name": "London",
            "countryCode": "UK",
            "isCapitol": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Birmingham",
            "countryCode": "UK",
            "isCapitol": false
        },
        {
            "name": "Bristol",
            "countryCode": "UK",
            "isCapitol": false
        },
        {
            "name": "Delhi",
            "countryCode": "IN",
            "isCapitol": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Hyderabad",
            "countryCode": "IN",
            "isCapitol": false
        } 
    ]
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the order from an array (with corresponding country names) and sort by capitol.

```js
const
    sortByCountry = (...countries) => (a, b) =>
        countries.indexOf(a.countryCode) - countries.indexOf(b.countryCode) ||
        b.isCapitol - a.isCapitol,
    array = [{ name: "Delhi", countryCode: "IN", isCapitol: true }, { name: "New York", countryCode: "USA", isCapitol: false }, { name: "Birmingham", countryCode: "UK", isCapitol: false }, { name: "London", countryCode: "UK", isCapitol: true }, { name: "Hyderabad", countryCode: "IN", isCapitol: false }, { name: "Chicago", countryCode: "USA", isCapitol: false }, { name: "Bristol", countryCode: "UK", isCapitol: false }, { name: "Washington", countryCode: "USA", isCapitol: true }];

array.sort(sortByCountry('USA', 'UK', 'IN'));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

ES5

```js
var sortByCountry = function () {
        var countries = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        return function (a, b) {
            return countries.indexOf(a.countryCode) - countries.indexOf(b.countryCode) ||
                b.isCapitol - a.isCapitol;
        }
    },
    array = [{ name: "Delhi", countryCode: "IN", isCapitol: true }, { name: "New York", countryCode: "USA", isCapitol: false }, { name: "Birmingham", countryCode: "UK", isCapitol: false }, { name: "London", countryCode: "UK", isCapitol: true }, { name: "Hyderabad", countryCode: "IN", isCapitol: false }, { name: "Chicago", countryCode: "USA", isCapitol: false }, { name: "Bristol", countryCode: "UK", isCapitol: false }, { name: "Washington", countryCode: "USA", isCapitol: true }];

array.sort(sortByCountry('USA', 'UK', 'IN'));

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you Nina, unfortunately our tool is not Es6 compatible . Can we achieve the same without spread operator?

Comment: Excellent.. Thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method and sort the country code by creating an ordering array, then by capital and at last, by city name.

```js
const sortByCountry = (data, order) =>
  data.sort(
    (x, y) =>
      order.indexOf(x.countryCode) - order.indexOf(y.countryCode) ||
      y.isCapitol - x.isCapitol ||
      x.name.localeCompare(y.name)
  );
const data = [
  {
    name: 'Delhi',
    countryCode: 'IN',
    isCapitol: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'New York',
    countryCode: 'USA',
    isCapitol: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'Birmingham',
    countryCode: 'UK',
    isCapitol: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'London',
    countryCode: 'UK',
    isCapitol: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'Hyderabad',
    countryCode: 'IN',
    isCapitol: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'Chicago',
    countryCode: 'USA',
    isCapitol: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'Bristol',
    countryCode: 'UK',
    isCapitol: false,
  },
  {
    name: 'Washington',
    countryCode: 'USA',
    isCapitol: true,
  },
];
const order = ['IND', 'USA', 'UK'];
console.log(sortByCountry(data, order));
```

Comment: Hi mr hr, Your code is working but the order of country is automatic descending order and not in our control ..its coincidental to the order what I am looking for. In other words what if  I want the order to be IND, USA, UK

Comment: @HarishPuli  Now check it. did it work for you? Please let me know.  I have updated the code.

Comment: Excellent.. Thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

In order to sort an array, you can use:

arr.sort([compareFunction])

So you would have to write a custom compareFunction

The compareFunction compares two any elements of the array and should return 1 if the first element is "bigger" or -1 if the first element is "smaller"

arr.sort((a, b) => (a > b) ? 1 : -1)

In this case our sorting function can receive any number of parameters, so we can access them in the *arguments* object. We can convert the arguments object into an array and use the indexOf function to compare the position of the country code in the array.

When the country code is the same, we check if one of the items is capitol.

```
randomCities =
  [
         {
             "name": "Delhi",
             "countryCode": "IN",
             "isCapitol": true
         },
         {
             "name": "New York",
             "countryCode": "USA",
             "isCapitol": false
         },
         {
             "name": "Birmingham",
             "countryCode": "UK",
             "isCapitol": false
         },
         {
             "name": "London",
             "countryCode": "UK",
             "isCapitol": true
         },
         {
             "name": "Hyderabad",
             "countryCode": "IN",
             "isCapitol": false
         },
         {
             "name": "Chicago",
             "countryCode": "USA",
             "isCapitol": false
         },
         {
             "name": "Bristol",
             "countryCode": "UK",
             "isCapitol": false
         },
         {
             "name": "Washington",
             "countryCode": "USA",
             "isCapitol": true
         }
     ]

function sortByCountry(){
  var args = Array.from(arguments);
  randomCities.sort( (a, b) => (args.indexOf(a.countryCode) == args.indexOf(b.countryCode)) ? (a.isCapitol ? -1 : 1) : ((args.indexOf(a.countryCode) > args.indexOf(b.countryCode)) ? 1 : -1));
  return randomCities;
}

sortyByCountry('USA', 'UK', 'IN');
```

Comment: Excellent.. Thank you very much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!